# Import functions from a module dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, import

I am having trouble with following task in nodejs/Javascript. I have multiple modules that depending to the situation will be imported (module1, module2, module3). I have managed to have them imported dynamically using
`var language = require(variable + 'path')`
The problem is that the function to use should also be dynamic and is not the same so sometimes I need function "create" from module1 but I can sometimes want function "update" instead of "create". I tried to have create/update (the option depending on the task) on a variable but it does not work to have language.variable because it assumes that "variable" is the name of the function in the module (I guess).

Is this even possible / Does anyone have a possible solution?

EDIT: I have e.g. module 1 and module 2. The user would specify in the platform which one he needs e.g. module 1 and what he wants to do with it, e.g. create a new person using that language (the function is also provided by the user e.g. createPerson({name:form.getFirstName, lastName: form.getLastName})). So in the backend I now have to import the module that I need (module 1) which I managed to do, but also I need to import the correct function e.g. "createPerson" from that module so that I can use the function provided by the user instantly. However as I have it right now, I did manage to have the function and library with which works and I will post it as answer unless someone has a better way to do it:

`expression.split('({',1)[0]`

`var language = require(variable + 'myPath')`

`` language[`${temp}`](expression) ``

temp has the first part of the expression provided by the user, in this case createPerson so that I can use it from the module dynamically. The problem I am facing now is that the expression is a string e.g. '{name:form.getFirstName, lastname:form.getLastName}' but should be an object. However JSON.parse does not work as it has code in it (I guess that's the problem) but I guess that is a different issue than the original post so I might create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my edit, this was achieved by using the following:

```
temp = expression.split('({',1)[0] 

var language = require(variable + 'myPath')

language[`${temp}`](expression)
```

This way I store the function name in temp, then with the variable I import the module necessary for the task and access the function that I need with the variable previously created

Answer (score 0):

```
function haveThisClassFunctionX(classInstance, functionName) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classInstance)
            .concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classInstance.__proto__))
            .filter(item => typeof classInstance[item] === 'function')
            .some(v => v === functionName);
}

class DeutschModule {
    constructor() {
        this.language = 'de';
    }
    create() {
        return this.language;
    }
}

class EnglishModule {
    constructor() {
        this.language = 'en';
    }
    create() {
        return this.language;
    }
    
    update() {
        return this.language;
    }
}

const languages = [
    new DeutschModule(),
    new EnglishModule(),
];


for (const lang of languages) {
    console.log(lang.constructor.name);
    console.log('has create: ' + haveThisClassFunctionX(lang, 'create'));
    console.log('has update: ' + haveThisClassFunctionX(lang, 'update'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the provided solution. However I need to import the function not check if the module has it. Would it be possible?

Comment: could you provide a simple fiddle on how you means it? i don't understand the question fully, because if you import an module, all functions the module exports are imported then.